# how to call a function into main() using different object in C?

Tags: java, c

I am new to C. I am trying to call a function. For example in below java program I have called a `machine()` method twice using object `concurrentMachine` in `main()`. By doing this I have two different values in `serviceInternal` variable. As a result, in `getCommonServiceInterval()`, I got `myService=12` and `concService=22;`.

```
public class Machine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Machine m = new Machine(12, true);
        m.concurrentMachine = new Machine(22, true);
        System.out.println("After " + m.getCommonServiceInterval() + " days both machine will need service at the same day." + 12 % 22);
    }

    abstract class Power {
        public int computerServiceInterval(int interval) {
            return interval;
        }
    }

    class FullPower extends Power {}

    class HalfPower extends Power {
        public int computerServicInterval(int interval) {
            return interval * 3;
        }
    }

    private Power powerState;
    private int serviceInterval;
    private Machine concurrentMachine;


    public Machine(int interval, boolean fullpower) {
        serviceInterval = interval;
        if (fullpower) this.powerState = this.new FullPower();
        else this.powerState = this.new HalfPower();
    }

    public int getServiceInterval() {
        return powerState.computerServiceInterval(serviceInterval);
    }

    public int getCommonServiceInterval() {
        int myService = this.getServiceInterval();
        int concService = concurrentMachine.getServiceInterval();
        return myService * concService;
    }
}
```

Now in C I have `machine()` function, but I couldn't call it into `main()` function using another object the way I can in Java so that I can have two values in `serviceInterval` in order to put values in `myService&concService`;

```
#define TRUE 1;
#define False 0;

int serviceInterval;
int fullpower(int interval);
int halfpower(int interval);
int computerServiceInterval(int interval);
void machine(int interval, char boolean_fullpower);
int getCommonServiceInterval();

int main() {
    machine(12, TRUE);
    //machine(22,TRUE);

    printf("After %d days both machine will need service at the same day.", getCommonServiceInterval());
    return 0;
}

void machine(int interval, char boolean_fullpower) {
    serviceInterval = interval;
    if (TRUE) fullpower(serviceInterval);
    else halfpower(serviceInterval);
}

int fullpower(int interval) {
    return computerServiceInterval(interval);
}

int halfpower(int interval) {
    int interval1 = interval * 3;
    return computerServiceInterval(interval1);
}

int computerServiceInterval(int interval) {
    return interval;
}

int getCommonServiceInterval() {
    int myService = computerServiceInterval(serviceInterval);
    //int concService=?;

    return myService * concService;
}
```

Note: I have to port this Java program to C, removing OO code. Sorry for my ugly coding.

Comment: Define your issue more precisely, why can't you call your method two times ?

Comment: What do you call `Object` in `C` ? Do you speak about `struct` ?

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end of the two `#define` statements. Also, the expression `if(TRUE)` will always be true, so the following `else` will never be executed.

Comment: C already has built-in boolean types.

Comment: "Couldn't call it into `main()` function using another object the way I can in Java" has no ascertainable meaning. Impossible to tell what you're talking about in this improperly capitalized and bizarrely formatted mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, Java is a full object language, so even `main` method has to be included in a class. C on the other end has no notion of classes. You what can you do to port OO code to C ? Use **`struct`**. A C struct is far from a real class because it can only hold attributes, but the is a common idiom to do OO programming in C is: *an OO method is translated in a function that take a pointer to struct as first argument*. No notion of protected, public, private anyway, but it should be enough.

Just use a factory function to create a new *object* through malloc, and do not forget to destroy (with free) any allocated object. Creation and destruction function allows to take care for any ancilliary subobject initialization and destruction. Code could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <error.h>

typedef enum _Power{FULLPOWER = 0, HALFPOWER} Power;

/* only if you C compiler has no native boolean */
typedef enum { false, true } boolean;

typedef struct _Machine {
    Power powerState;
    int serviceInterval;
    struct _Machine* concurrentMachine;
} Machine;

int computerServiceInterval(int interval, Power power) {
    static const int factor[] = {1, 3}; /* one value per enum in Power in same order */
    return interval * factor[power];
}

/* constructor factory function */
Machine* createMachine(int interval, boolean fullpower) {
    Machine* machine = malloc(sizeof(Machine));
    if (machine == NULL) return NULL;
    machine->serviceInterval = interval;
    machine->powerState = fullpower ? FULLPOWER : HALFPOWER;
    machine->concurrentMachine = NULL;
    return machine;
}

/* destruction (including eventual suobject) */
void destroyMachine(Machine *machine) {
    if (machine->concurrentMachine != NULL) destroyMachine(machine->concurrentMachine);
    free(machine);
}

int getServiceInterval(Machine *machine) {
    return computerServiceInterval(machine->serviceInterval, machine->powerState);
}

int getCommonServiceInterval(Machine *machine) {
    return machine->serviceInterval * machine->concurrentMachine->serviceInterval;
}
int main() {
    Machine* m = createMachine(12, true);
    if (m == NULL) {
        perror("ERROR allocating machine");
        return 1;
    }
    m->concurrentMachine = createMachine(22, true);
    if (m == NULL) {
        perror("ERROR allocating concurrent machine");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("After %d days both machine will need service at the same day.\n",
        getCommonServiceInterval(m));
    destroyMachine(m); /* don't forget destruction */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ Serge Ballesta    thanks...  i did the program using your guidelines almost similar to you but dont know how to put in comment box...btw the program is showing " fatal error: 'malloc.h' file not found " during compiling

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete solution to your Java code (which would be pretty long), but it should give you an idea how to do this. This could be improved in many ways, for example by using function pointer or an enum or something for `Power`, but better keep things simple if you're not too familiar with C:

You'll need at least these includes for the code below:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>
```

First, you need a `struct Machine` in C, to take place of the `class Machine` of Java, something like:

```
struct Machine {
   bool fullPower; // false is half power
   int serviceInterval;
   struct Machine *concurrentMachine;
}
```

Then, to replace Java constructor and new, you can create a function which allocates and initializes the Machine struct:

```
struct Machine * new_Machine(int serviceInterval, bool fullPower){
    struct Machine *this = malloc(sizeof(struct Machine));
    this->fullPower = fullPower;
    this->serviceInterval = serviceInterval;
    this->concurrentMachine = NULL;
    return this;
}
```

C has no garbage collection, so you must call `free` yourself. Since that is a data structure which has pointers in it which also need to be freed, you probably want a function like this:

```
void destroy_Machines(struct Machine *m) {
    while(m) {
        struct Machine *tmp = m;
        m = m->concurrentMachine;
        // add other desctuctor stuff if needed
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

Then to create "methods", just pass them pointer to struct, which you might want to name `this` to keep things familiar (note: using `this` in C can be either a blessing or a curse if you ever need to port this to C++, depending on how you do it). Example:

```
int compute_Machine_ServiceInterval(struct Machine *this){
    ASSERT(this); // will abort if you accidentally call this with NULL
    return this->fullPower 
                 ? this->serviceInterval
                 : this->serviceInterval * 3; 
}    

int compute_Machine_ServiceIntervalSum(struct Machine *this) {
    ASSERT(this);
    int sum = compute_Machine_ServiceInterval(this);
    if (this->concurrentMachine) {
        sum += compute_Machine_ServiceInterval(this->concurrentMachine);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Then to replace start of your Java `main`, you do something like this:

```
int main() {
    struct Machine *m = new_Machine(12, true);
    m->concurrentMachine = new_Machine(22, true);

    // add more methods and call them properly, just dummy example here:
    int serviceIntervalSum = compute_Machine_ServiceIntervalSum(m) 

    // clean up
    destroy_machines(m);
    return 0;
}
```